# Empty Cells and Null Valuess

Tags: python, arrays

I've got an array that contains data including the following:

```
1984    NR
1983    NR
1982    6
1981    0
1980    20
1979    9
1978    10
```

The data set is much larger, and contains enough information that can be analyzed as a regression or other form. How can I write code that takes `NR` (which stands for "No Reading") and makes the value empty? To this point, I've simply left out the data, and I've written code as follows:

```
from numpy import loadtxt, empty
from pylab import scatter, xlabel, ylabel, xlim, ylim, show, plot
from scipy import stats

data = loadtxt("Durham_1.txt")
x = data[ : ,0]
y = data[ : ,1]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print slope
print intercept
```

The problem is that I've got a very large data set, and I'd like to be able to run the program while assigning the `NR` values as some type of null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are wanting is a system for analyzing data that contains both numeric and non-numeric entities.  There are a number of possible ways to approach this situation and the algorithm that you ultimately use will have to have a method for distinguishing between numeric and non-numeric data.

One way is to choose a flag value.  A flag value is a numeric value that is not valid for the range of actual numeric values in your data set.  For example, if your data set contains only positive numbers, then you might choose a flag value of -1.0 to indicate "no result".

Another way is to use a reference type to contain your numeric data such as `Double`.  You can set the variable to `null` to indicate a non-numeric quantity.  There are disadvantages to this approach:

- You can have only a single flag value (`null`)
- An object must be allocated for every observation in your data set

A third way is to build a class to represent observations in your data set.  One field would contain the numeric value, and another field would indicate the "status" of the observation.  For example, you might use the status field to flag "No Result" or "Invalid Data" or any of a number of possible values.

This last option has the advantage of working for observations for which there is no practical "flag value" in the range of possible values (as the status is stored separately).  It shares the disadvantage of requiring an object allocation for every observation.